# iPhone Simple submit form

Tags: iphone, sdk

how can i create a simple submit form with some UITextfield and button , when user tabs the button then the textfield information sends into an email (without email application) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, use a [grouped table view](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ContentViews/ContentViews.html), with a cell that contains a text field and a button.

For your second question, take a look at the [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) project on Google Code, which "implements a quick class for sending one off messages via SMTP on the iPhone".

Comment: thank you but is there any simple way ?  i don't want use grouped table view

Comment: Just place a text field and a button wherever you want them. Generally, however, people expect forms to look like grouped table views.